# How can I disable automatic line breaks in bugzilla?

Tags: bugzilla

Typing in the Bugzilla-Comment-box is no problem.. line break is working there as desired.

But if I write a comment with a long line, this line breaks after 85 chars.

How to avoid them? Long lines written in the comment-box should be shown as long lines in the comment-history/-timeline

Running Bugzilla-de version 4.4-1

I'm "only" an end-user.. so i need i solution to make a change without admin-/server-permission(s)

Answer (score 0):

I guess your problem is same as this bugzilla bug [Bug 11901 - Change Bugzilla comments line-wrapping policy](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=11901)

Not sure what to do :( ,  but they have fixed it in version 2.20.1 .

Comment: Thanks 4 input.. I think, it is the problem.. I edited my text above cause I'm "only" an end-user ;-)